# macOS Photos app choking when importing from an iPhone 6s

Tags: macos, photos.app

I have a early 2015, 11" MacBook Air and an iPhone 6s running iOS 12.1.4. On my MacBook, I am using Photos App Version 4.0 (3421.5.230).

I open Photos.app, connect the iPhone via USB, select **Import all new items**, and the MacBook will start, then hang up on the import just sitting there for hours.

I have run First Aid ran and have updated all the devices and app but to no avail.

What else should I look for to resolve the issue?

any ideas?

Comment: I'd double-check the same happens if you import via Image Capture [which is the underlying engine used by Photos]. Test importing to a folder rather than to Photos itself, you can always drop them to Photos later, if it works. If it does, the issue might be with Photos' database. if it doesn't, it might be the phone.

Comment: I used Image Capture and there were no errors. I've created a new Photos library, but still get the same problem. But at least I have a work around now, thanks

Comment: @Tetsujin Same issue Photos keep crashing. Image Capture worked. +1 for the solution.